# Simulation Model

Tags: simulation

How do I find the Inter-arrival time when the Inter-arrival time is described on as exponentially distributed with mean of 12 minutes? This is a single server model with a generalized service time. I have the information for the service time and its probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with mean $\lambda^{-1}$ the probability density function is $\lambda \exp(-\lambda t)$ for $t \ge 0$  The link is the first response in Google to the phrase.